# CSS Showing small box in page

Tags: html, css

In my question form page, small boxes are display , i dont know what is that ,

how it is displaying ,

I i remve the form tag, that that stupid small box are vanished,

Can u tell me , y small box are displaying.,

Thanks
[link text](http://qa.ukatn.com/totallydriven/feedback/submit-feedback.php)

[alt text http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/7421/questionformprobl.jpg](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/7421/questionformprobl.jpg)

Comment: A link to "question form page" would be useful.

Comment: @jens: I think its available besides 'Thanks'. But i cannot see small boxes that OP is telling.

Comment: And a more telling description than "small boxes"

Comment: @OP: You have given a wrong link then.

Comment: The page you posted is blank in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in which browser do you see these 'small boxes'?
In IE6 en IE7 it looks fine.

regard,
Stijn

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the slightly irregular white space in your bottom image:

[alt text http://qa.ukatn.com/totallydriven/images/lonsky.gif](http://qa.ukatn.com/totallydriven/images/lonsky.gif)

those are in the image, they don't come from CSS.

I can't see anything else wrong with the page (Firefox 3.6, IE8, Windows 7).